# Upating centos using yum

Tags: linux, redhat, yum, update, rhn

I am trying to update my system, been looking but cannot find any solution to my problem. When I execute `yum update` I am getting following error

```
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, rhnplugin
There was an error communicating with RHN.
Red Hat Satellite or RHN Classic support will be disabled.
rhn-plugin: Error communicating with server. The message was:
Unable to connect to the host and port specified
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * epel: fedora-epel.mirror.lstn.net
No packages marked for update
```

I actually have no idea which files to look and what to change. Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Updating RHEL requires a valid RHEL subscription.

The error message you received indicates that your server was not able to contact the relevant server to verify its subscription status.

If you are using Satellite, you need to check that you have network connectivity to the Satellite server.

If you are not using Satellite and receive updates directly from Red Hat, you need to [migrate to RHEL Subscription Management](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_subscription_management/1/html/migrating_from_rhn_classic/rhn-migrate-classic) using the `rhn-migrate-classic-to-rhsm` utility. The old Red Hat Network was decommissioned some time ago.

If you haven't got a RHEL subscription, you need to purchase one, or switch to CentOS.

If your system somehow really is CentOS, then you need to remove the `yum-rhn-plugin` package: `yum -y remove yum-rhn-plugin` This package should not be installed on CentOS systems unless they are talking to Spacewalk/Satellite.

Comment: You can try to use other repos like EPEL that don't require a subscription. But they aren't as supported as the official RHEL repositories: https://www.tecmint.com/how-to-enable-epel-repository-for-rhel-centos-6-5. Best just to sort out the licensing issue